# Finding a totally dual integral system $Ax\leq b$ with $A$ and $b$ integral.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, vector-spaces, convex-analysis

**Exercise:** Let $P = \text{conv.hull}(\{(0,0),(1,2),(2,0)\})$. Find a totally dual integral (TDI) system $Ax\leq b$ with $A$ and $b$ integral, such that $P = \{x:Ax\leq b\}$.

**Solution:** The polytope $P$ is described by the following system:$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1\\
-2 & 1\\
2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}x \leq \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\4\end{bmatrix}.$$ It now suffices to find a Hilbert basis for each of the three cones generated by two of the rows. Given any two integral vectors $u$, $v$ it suffices to take the integral points in $\{\lambda_1 u + \lambda_2v: 0\leq \lambda_1,\lambda_2 <1\}$.

i) For the first and second row, we add $$\begin{bmatrix}-1 &0\end{bmatrix}x\leq 0.$$

ii) For the first and third row, we add $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 &0\end{bmatrix}x \leq 2.$$

iii) For the second and third row, we add $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\0&1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}x\leq\begin{bmatrix}3\\2\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$

There's an awful lot about this solution that I don't understand, so I have a couple of questions:

**Questions:**

- At the start of this solution immediately the desired system is given. How do you construct this system? And are we not done if this is the system that describes $P$? (I imagine we are not done because this system is not TDI yet, but I'm asking to be sure).
- The solution states that it suffices to find a Hilbert basis for each of the three cones generated by two of the rows. Why does this system generate cones, and how do *two* of the rows generate *three* cones? Furthermore, what is the purpose of taking the integral points in $\{\lambda_1 u + \lambda_2 v:0\leq \lambda_1, \lambda_2 <1\}$ where $u,v$ are two integral vectors?
- I don't understand what's being achieved in steps i)-iii). What is added and what for? If the initial system is not TDI, what does the TDI system look like?

I understand that this is probably a lot. If you think that there's a better way to help me understand this exercise, feel free to ignore the specific questions I posed.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I've looked up the definitions of a cone and a Hilbert basis online and they differ somewhat from the definitions in my book. Please use the following:

- **Def 1:** Denote by cone($S$) the convex cone generated by $S$: the set of all nonnegative linear combinations of vectors in $S$.
- **Def 2:** The set $S$ is called a Hilbert basis (of cone $C$) if every integral vector in $C$ is a nonnegative integer combination of vectors in $S$.